# Missing a return statement somewhere?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on a basic Java assignment for school. This snippet involves searching for a specific part number in an ArrayList. When I try to compile, the IDE says I have a missing return statement. However, I can't see where it is. Do I need a return statement following the increment of the index? If so, then the return null becomes unreachable. Thank you guys very much.

```
        public InventoryItem findInventoryItem(int searchPartNumber)
{
    int index = 0;
    boolean searching = true;
    while (index < items.size() && searching){
        InventoryItem inventoryItem = items.get(index);
        int fetchedPartNumber = inventoryItem.getPartNumber();
        if(fetchedPartNumber == (searchPartNumber)){
            searching = false;
            return inventoryItem;
        }
        else{
            index++;
        }

        if(searching){
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: imagine situation that `items.size() == 0`, what will be returned from your function?

Comment: Or when `fetchedPartNumber` is not equal to `searchPartNumber` in all cases, Or `fetchedPartNumber` is null, or... Suggest OP re-writes the method body somewhat.

Comment: The `searching` variable appears to be redundant. In the only case in which it is set to `false`, you return immediately after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code has several problems:

1. after you compared first item in list and it does not match - you will stop comparing, as searching is true and you will return null
2. in case of empty list you need to return null too

here is the fixed version:

```
public InventoryItem findInventoryItem(int searchPartNumber) {
    for (InventoryItem inventoryItem : items)
        if (inventoryItem.getPartNumber() == searchPartNumber)
            return inventoryItem;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Although this assignment requires a while loop, it is still very helpful as a beginner to see how this also works in a for loop. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The method expected a return value in all cases. This means you have to add a return value in the else-block, too. Or you could add a return value only once at the end of all statements.

Answer (score 0):

you're not handling the case where search will not be true.

That is,

```
 if(searching){
            return null;
        }
```

Where is the else part handled here?

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem that I didn't really see.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what happens in your method, there has to be some value returned (even if it is null).

Right now, if you never get into your while (because that condition isn't fulfilled to begin with -> like when items.size() is 0), your method won't return anything.

In other words: Put a return null; after the closing bracket of your while loop.

Another important note: You do realize that this while will always only look at the first item, right? Because if your first item is not the one you're searching for, your variable searching will still be true, which will then force the method to return null (without looking at any other items)

Comment: Thanks for the great, clear answer. I've removed the searching boolean as it doesn't really need to be there, as well as added the return after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to return if `items.size` equals zero. Second you need to return if you find nothing. Third I can't see any usefulness of the variable `searching`.
You could change your searching function a bit. The final form would be something like this:

```
public InventoryItem findInventoryItem(int searchPartNumber) {
    int index = 0;
    while (index < items.size()){
        InventoryItem inventoryItem = items.get(index);
        int fetchedPartNumber = inventoryItem.getPartNumber();

        if(fetchedPartNumber == searchPartNumber)
            return inventoryItem;

        else
            index++;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I see how the searching boolean isn't needed, as the return fits in after the while loop nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `return` statement right at the end, after the `while` loop.

This is needed to handle the case where the `while` loop guard becomes false, either by `items` being empty, or `searching` being set to `false`.

The compiler has no way of determining whether these will never become false, so you it requires you to return in case they do.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, all possible outcomes are now accounted for!

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
    public InventoryItem findInventoryItem(int searchPartNumber)
    {
        int index = 0;
        //boolean searching = true; comment out this line
        InventoryItem inventoryItem = null; //declare null InventoryItem here
        while (index < items.size())
        {
            inventoryItem = items.get(index);
            int fetchedPartNumber = inventoryItem.getPartNumber();
            if (fetchedPartNumber == (searchPartNumber))
            {
                //searching = false; comment out this line
                break; //do something to get out from while loop
            }
            else {
                inventoryItem = null;
                index++;
            }
        }

        return inventoryItem; //if found then it will have item otherwise null
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All functions that have a type (aren't void) require that you return something based on the method signature.  This means that you must return something in ALL cases.  You haven't included the case where searching is not true, and must return something if that is the case.

```
        if(searching){
          return null;
        } else{
          //return something else
        }
```

It is important to note though that in this case the else is implicit, and therefore you don't actually have to provide the else.  You could instead just do this:

```
        if(searching){
          return null;
        }
        //return something else
```

Keep in mind that if searching is true, it will return null and "return something else" will never be called.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I appreciate it. I removed the searching boolean, as it wasn't really essential for the function of this code.