# Return boolean with an if inside a try

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I dont know why aI can't return the true or false. It prints "missing return statement."
I have looked for answers in the web, but none of them solves my problem.

```
public boolean Verification(String SQL) throws IOException{
    try{
        Statement statementCount=connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = statementCount.executeQuery(SQL);

        String Cont=results.getString("ContadorFecha");
        int cont=Integer.parseInt(Cont);
        if (cont>=10){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }catch(SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception in register: " + ex);
        }

}
```

Comment: You don't return anything in the `catch` block. So there is a missing return statement, as the error says.

Comment: *"but none of them solves my problem"* Sorry, but that's just completely untrue. There are *thousands* of versions of this question, with clear answers, many of them right here on SO. The briefest search gives us [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33536284/java-missing-return-statement-after-try-catch) with `try/catch`, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788204/missing-return-statement-error-in-java) with `if/else`, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35806909/missing-a-return-statement-somewhere) with just `if`...

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a return statement for all the scenario's possible.

In this example, it seems to be, because of this:

```
if (cont>=10){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

which could actually be replaced by:

```
return cont >= 10;
```

but: what if there's an Exception thrown before that?

The try block is finished, and this is handled (if it's this type of Exception, anyway)

```
catch(SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception in register: " + ex);
        }
```

add a

```
return false;
```

after your catch block, and all your cases will be covered. The JVM will know for each scenario what to return, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Its missing a return statement because of your catch block.

You either need to return something in there as well, or throw an Exception.

Comment: Only half the answer: what if another (not caught) type of Exception is thrown?

Comment: > what if another (not caught) type of Exception is thrown

If a RuntimeException is thrown you don't need a return in that case (obviously)

Comment: that means the catch block will not run, so if you only have a return statement, or throws Exception in that catch block, you still need to cover the possibility of another Exception being thrown.

Comment: I really don't get what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: try{
  // code that throws NullPointerException
  return value;
}catch(SQLException e){
  // CATCHES ONLY SQLEXCEPTION, not the NPE
  return otherValue;
}
// still no return value for the case caused by the NPE

Comment: @Stultuske:

Yes...BUT so what? If a Runtime Exception is thrown, or if an Exception is thrown that leaves the method, then you don't need a return....

Example:
public String test() throws IOException {
  if(new Random().nextBoolean()) {
   throw new IOException();
  }
  throw new RuntimeException();
 }

Comment: @Stultuske: Adding a `return` to the `catch` block is all that's required. If something that isn't an `SQLException` occurs, the method *throws*, it doesn't *return*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder nyah ... long day

Comment: @911DidBush just ignore my remarks

Answer (score 0):

Simply change it to this:

```
public boolean Verification(String SQL) throws IOException {
    try {
        Statement statementCount = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = statementCount.executeQuery(SQL);

        String Cont = results.getString("ContadorFecha");
        int cont = Integer.parseInt(Cont);
        if (cont >= 10) {
            return true;
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exception in register: " + ex);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean Verification(String SQL) throws IOException{
      Boolean flag=false;
        try{
            Statement statementCount=connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet results = statementCount.executeQuery(SQL);

            String Cont=results.getString("ContadorFecha");
            int cont=Integer.parseInt(Cont);
            if (cont>=10){
                flag=true;
            }

        }catch(SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Exception in register: " + ex);
            }
        return flag;

    }
```